# How do I use the index function in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

If I try to programatically reference the index

7.10

The natural round by python inhibits my ability to make reference to the position 
line 7

 position 10

How would I be able to do this programmatically?

 x = 7.10

output: 

>>> 7.1

Comment: @PaulRooney it involves tkinter because I'm using a text widget and navigating that programmatically

Comment: If you are talking about text widget indexes, they are _strings_, not floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you make x a string:

```
x="7.10"
```

then split into a dictionary with line and position split out:

```
dict = {"line": x.split(".")[0], "position": x.split(".")[1]}
```

output:

```
{'line': '7', 'position': '10'}
```

Comment: found that the index can be used as a string and can therefore avoid the natural round by python. Thank you so much for input!

Comment: just wanted to add that you can use a string as an index reference. I.E. tkinter_window.get(x) where x = "7.10". No need to complicate things with dictionaries etc :)